# Rails + Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I want to ask some question about using Rails (2.1.0) and Ruby (1.8.7).

I have development mode and production. Production mode has a domain (for example `blabla.online.com`), development mode has an ip adress (for example `199.199.199.199`).

QUESTION: Do I need to create two different accounts in analytics (one for development and one for production)?

Comment: You should be more specific with your question. I count 4 questions in your post, focusing on one of these will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I dont think so, you can choose to show ads on multiple domains... you can filter revenue by domain aswell, or setup different channels. Then based on the env in rails, pick a channel. Ideally you shouldn't be showing ads in dev mode Rails.env == "development"

Comment: @AbePetrillo aren't you confusing analytics with adwords?

Comment: @Ahmet could you expand this in an answer? Telling him why it doesn't matter where his site is, how to filter development visits, etc.

Comment: Because you can just use one.. No need for creating more than one account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want multiple "Accounts", but you do want multiple "Website Profiles".

1. Login to Google Analytics, you should be on a page with title "Overview: all accounts"
2. Click on the link for the correct account (in your example it's probably called "online").
3. You should now be on a page with title "Overview >> online" that shows a list of all website profiles associated with this account.
4. At the bottom of the table click "Add website profile"

Note that your new website profile will have a different tracking ID (e.g. the thing that looks like `UA-255235386-2`) so you'll need to have an environment specific configuration in your Rails app to use the appropriate tracking ID for the appropriate environment.

Comment: Cool, I used to disable analytics in development, but it added a manual testing operation when deploying in production. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah, I've found it pretty helpful to have a "development environment" for Google Analytics.  Especially if you are working within a cycle that has a formal QA period and a separate QA site, it's a good idea to go take a look at the GA data generated during that QA period and make sure it looks sensible.  Since GA accounts are free, there is really no reason not to do this.